# jquery colorbox load page in popup on button click

Tags: jquery, popup

I want to load a html page in popup. I did some google and found jquery [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox). The examples that they have given uses `anchor tag` but I want to load popup on button click.

Example given for colorbox

```
<a class='iframe' href="http://wikipedia.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
});
```

in above example of colorbox they are loading a external page in popup on click of link but I want to do that on click of button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<input type="button" id="yourButtonId" value="Load Page" />

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yourButtonId").on("click", function() {
     $.fn.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
     //or
     $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
  });     
});
```

Comment: jQuery.fn.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"}) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

By placing the colorbox in `$(document).ready(function(){`, the popup is being created upon page load.

Simply bind a click event to the button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourButtonId').click(function () {
        $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind this code on button click:

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({open:true, iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

`$(".iframe")` - must have `href` tag

`open:true` - will open colorbox after button click

Answer (score 0):

Use the anchor tag and surround the text with button tag:

```
    <a class='iframe' href="http://wikipedia.com">
    <button>Outside Webpage (Iframe)</button></a>
```